# Pass array from one component to the other in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular app, I am trying to pass the array `playlist` from one component (1) to the other (2). What would be the best approach for this. *@Input?*

**Component1.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../../services/api.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faRedo } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faHeadphones } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faExternalLinkAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class ContentComponent {

  public data = [];
  public playlist = [];
  public apiData: any;
  public results = [];
  public loading = false;
  public noData: any;
  p: number = 1;
  faSearch = faSearch;
  faRedo = faRedo;
  faHeadphones = faHeadphones;
  faExternalLinkAlt = faExternalLinkAlt;
  faPlus = faPlus;

  searchQuery: string = "";
  clickMessage = '';

  constructor(private service: ApiService) { }

  getAll() {
    this.service.getAll(this.searchQuery).subscribe((results) => {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('Data is received - Result - ', results);
      this.data = results.results;
      this.loading = false;

      if (this.data.length <= 0) {
        this.noData = true;
      } else if (this.data.length >= 1) {
        this.noData = false;
      } else {
        this.noData = false;
      }
    })
  }

  closeAlert() {
    this.noData = false;
  }

  addSongToPlaylist(itunes) {
    this.playlist.push(itunes);
    console.log('Playlist - ', this.playlist);
}

  refresh(): void {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  Search() {
    this.service.getAll(this.searchQuery).subscribe((results) => {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('Data is received - Result - ', results);
      this.data = results.results;
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

**Component2.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { faHeadphones} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  faHeadphones = faHeadphones;

  @Input()playlist = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: there are many methods of component communication, primary methods are inputs (pass data to children), ouputs (pass data to parents) or shared services (pass data between arbitrary components)

Comment: How would you pass the array with the inputs method, as I see that is mostly with Strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Input to pass array, but the children component will get reference of **playlist**.
If you want to pass copy of playlist then do this way
In **ContentComponent**

```
playlistToPass = JSON.stringify(this.playlist);
```

then convert back to array in HeaderComponent

```
playlist = JSON.parse(this.playlistPassed);
```

Comment: There objects in the array

Comment: The playlist is array of objects. There is no problem in using JSON.stringify() to convert array of objects to  json string .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way to do this I found was via a service. This then gets passed into the `constrctor` of the component.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlaylistService {

  public playlist = [];

  constructor() { 

  }
}
```